# Couldn't Create a Trigger. Error 1235

Tags: mysql, database, forms, codeigniter, triggers

I have talked to my hosting provider after I got this error. I thought that It's about mysql. But they said to me, it is about my tables on my database and also the codes I have used as query.

It's the first time ever I use Trigger in Php. Because of this I couldn't solve the problem even I checked my codes and searched about the problem on the internet.

Firstly, I want to tell you what I want to do. I have three tables in my database. These are users, user_hobbies and hobbies.

In users table there are 5 columns.

`user_id | user_name | user_surname | user_mail | user_phonenumber`

In hobbies table there are 2 columns.

```
hobbies_id | hobbies_name
```

In user_hobbies table there are 2 columns.

```
user_id | hobbies_id
```

There are two forms. One of two is for adding hobbies. I added some hobbies such as swimming, fishing and etc and the hobbies are shown in a list menu on registration form that is the second form. Before submit the registration form, a user has to fill the blanks like below.

User Name, User Surname, User Mail, User Phone Number and Hobbies.

After submit the form the data will should insert like below. As an example,

```
user_id | user_name | user_surname | user_mail | user_phonenumber
   1       barita       baritax      example@      123-1234567
                                     example.com
   2       stack        overflow     example2@     147-1478963
                                     example.com


hobbies_id | hobbies_name
     1         swimming
     2         fishing
     3         drawing

user_id | hobbies_id
   1          1
   2          1
   2          2
```

To do this, I need to use trigger as I search on the internet and also I read some solutions here. So first challenge for me, to write the user_id into the user_hobbies table when it is written to the users table. And also second challenge is to write the hobbies_id's next to the user's id. But for the first challenge I need your help.

I have use CodeIgniter by the way. The codes I tried trigger is below.

My model.php

```
public function add_usershobbies($post)
{   
    $this->db->query("CREATE TRIGGER first_trig AFTER INSERT ON users
                        FOR EACH ROW
                        BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO user_hobbies VALUES(new.user_id);
                        END;");
}
```

I expect from this query, the user_id should be inserting into the two tables users and user_hobbies.

But I got error when I submit the registration form with this query. The error is below.

Error Number: 1235

This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

CREATE TRIGGER first_trig AFTER INSERT ON user FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO user_hobbies VALUES(new.user_id); END;

Filename: /home/example.com/httpdocs/models/model.php

Line Number: 64

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: So the error is clear that you already have a trigger `after insert` on  `users`.

Comment: I don't know how it is possible :) Because I tried many times to use trigger and I got some errors every time. I have never seen success in somewhere with trigger during I tried to use it. How can I have a trigger? It's magic. So what to do? I am confused a bit. Should I remove this query if I have already? Can I use like $this->db->insert('users', $post); $this->db->insert('user_hobbies', $post); instead of create trigger query?

Comment: Login to mysql and try this command `show triggers ;` this will list all the existing triggers you have.

Comment: Yes I show I really have already one a trigger. It's strange. Anyway. So how should I use it in my model.php?

Comment: You can add an additional query as `$this->db->query("drop trigger if exists first_trig");` before executing the `create trigger` command.

Comment: I wrote that query before create a trigger and still same. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Oh wait. I have only used your query instead of mine and then the error is not seen. I guess we are on right way. But now when I submit the form, the user is not inserted on the table. But it was worked before. What's the point I have missed?

Comment: So now I fixed I guess. I have used your query and the user_id is not inserted into the other table.